# Fixed Point Iteration - Finding Iteration Functions

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, expression-manipulation

When we use [*Solve*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), it attempts to solve the system for the variables, for example

```
  Solve[x^3 + 4 x^2 - 10 == 0, x]
```

If we want to use Fixed Point Iteration to solve this, we need to find target functions, $x = g_i(x)$, and these include

- $x = g_1(x) = x - x^3 - 4x^2 + 10$
- $x = g_2(x) = \left(\dfrac{10}{x} - 4 x\right)^{1/2}$
- $x = g_3(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}(10 - x^3)^{1/2}$
- $x = g_4(x) = \left(\dfrac{10}{4+x}\right)^{1/2}$
- $x = g_5(x) = x - \dfrac{x^3+4x^2-10}{3x^2+8x}$

Not all of them will work of course, but my question, is there some way to get Solve or some other function to not solve all the way through and to generate all these target functions? I tried looking at other MMA functions, but nothing jumped out at me.

Also, could the method extend to multi-variable functions?

Comment: There are infinitely many such functions that you could `FixedPoint` iterate over. One way to generate some of them might be to randomly replace  a single `x` in the equation with `u` and, collect `u` on one side of the expression, then put `x` back by replacing `u` with `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Bill's answer here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/223878/72682 and my idea in the comments I've created a generator for your $g(x)$. It is by no means general and for many expressions it will probably fail because of the `Solve` to reorganize the equation as $x=g(x)$:

```
generateG[expr_] := 
 Module[{pos = Position[expr, x], thispos, subexpr, mashed, urepl},
  thispos = #[[1 ;; RandomInteger[{1, Length@#}]]] &@RandomChoice[pos];
  subexpr = Extract[expr, thispos];
  mashed = ReplacePart[expr, thispos -> u];
  urepl = RandomChoice[TimeConstrained[Solve[mashed == 0, x], 5]];
  ((x /. urepl) /. u -> subexpr)
 ]
Table[Quiet[
   Check[x[n + 1] == (generateG[x^3 + 4 x^2 - 10] /. x -> x[n]), 
    Nothing]], 10] // DeleteDuplicates
```

This is good enough for polynomials and finds a few slightly different $g(x)$. The `Check` and `Quiet` part is to shut up `Solve` when it fails.
I tried it on some weirder equations like $x^2 \tanh (2 x)-3=0$ and it gave me this:

```
expr = Tanh[2 x] x^2 - 3
DeleteDuplicates[
 Table[Quiet[
   Check[x[n + 1] == (generateG[expr] /. x -> x[n]), Nothing]], 10]]
(* results ... x[1 + n] == Sqrt[3]/Sqrt[Tanh[2 x[n]]] *)
```

... and the fixed point iteration worked, with an error of about 10^-5 at 50 iterations:

```
result = Nest[Sqrt[3]/Sqrt[Tanh[2 #]] &, 1., 50]
(* result: 1.73374 *)
expr /. result
(* 9.70892*10^-6 *)
```

Comment: This is excellent! Thank you, I will play around with it a bunch!