# Replace a randomly chosen part of an expression

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

Given an arbitrary *Mathematica* expression, how can I choose a random part of the expression and replace it with another symbol of my choosing?

For example, given $a x^3 +2y\cos(x)- \tanh(x^{y+3})/(x^4-\sqrt{b})$, I want to select a single randomly chosen part of the expression that involves an $x$ term and replace it with $\mathbf{u}$. This part could be any sub-expression with an $x$ such as  $x^3,a x^3, 2y\cos(x),\cos(x),x, x^{y+3},\tanh(x^{y+3}),x^4,(x^4-\sqrt{b})$, or even the whole expression. Examples:

$$
\mathbf{u}\\
\mathbf{u} +2y\cos(x)- \tanh(x^{y+3})/(x^4-\sqrt{b})\\
a x^3 +2y\cos(x)- \tanh(x^{y+3})/\mathbf{u}\\
a x^3 +2y\cos(x)- \tanh(\mathbf{u})/(x^4-\sqrt{b})\\
a x^3 +\mathbf{u}- \tanh(x^{y+3})/(x^4-\sqrt{b})\\
a x^3 +2y\cos(x)- \mathbf{u}/(x^4-\sqrt{b})\\
\mathbf{u} - \tanh(x^{y+3})/(x^4-\sqrt{b})\\
a x^3 + 2y\cos(x) - \mathbf{u}\\
a x^3 + \mathbf{u}
$$

Also I'd like to know which subexpression was chosen for replacement with $\mathbf{u}$. So far I've been able to generate random replacements like this:

```
expr = a x^3 + 2 y Cos[x] - Tanh[x^(y + 3)]/(x^4 - Sqrt[b]);
Table[ReplacePart[expr, 
 RandomChoice[Position[expr, _, Heads -> False]] -> u], 
 1000] // DeleteDuplicates
```

...but I have not been able to 1) only select expressions involving $x$, and 2) record which subexpression was chosen.

For clarification, the following image shows the expression tree for the example I gave above. Green nodes are eligible for replacement with $\mathbf{u}$ because they contain $x$ or some sub-expression involving $x$. Red nodes do not contain any $x$ and are not eligible for replacement:

[image: expression tree]

Comment: Is this in relation to [(223870)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/223870/27951)?

Comment: @MarcoB yes, but I think it's a useful question in its own right, and applies to other things like fuzzing and genetic algorithms - it would be a bit hidden if I explored it in that question.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to break all the terms of a power, like $x^3 = x x x$ in the expression first, because it is possible to only replace one $x$ and keep the others in the power also? For example, you could replace $x^3$ as $u x^2$.

Comment: @Moo Good point. That would be interesting to see if you know how to implement it, but it's probably quite tricky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
expr = a x^3 + 2 y Cos[x] - Tanh[x^(y + 3)]/(x^4 - Sqrt[b]);
pos = Position[expr, x];
thisPos = RandomChoice[pos]; 
ReplacePart[expr, Drop[thisPos, -RandomInteger[{0, Length[thisPos] - 1}]] -> u]
```

Each time you execute it, you select a random term containing x from the expression and replace it with u.

Comment: This will not select parts like `Cos[x]` or `Tanh[x^(y+3)]` - it will just replace the 'leaf' terms `x`. I want to replace any part of the expression tree provided it involves an `x` term at some leaf.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement... every possible combination of symbols in the expression "involve x" in some way. If you can replace a x^2 with u then why not replace Co[x]+a x^2 with u?

Comment: When I execute your code many times it just replaces a random $x$ with $u$. _every possible combination of symbols in the expression "involve x" in some way_ -  take $(y+3)$ and $2y$, they do not involve $x$. If you take the TreeForm of the expression, I want to replace a random node with $u$ provided that node is $x$ or it has some descendent node $x$. So that also covers things like replacing `Tanh[x^(y+3)]`, `x^(y+3)`, `x` by itself, or even the whole expression since it trivially involves $x$.

Comment: Thanks,  your edit mostly works. The only slight problem is it sometimes chooses sub-expressions like this one for example `2 a x^3 + 2 y Cos[x]`, which doesn't appear in the expression and replaces nothing. I'm not sure why as I tried a similar approach moments ago and it happened to me also.

Comment: OK.. but the expression 2 a x^3 + 2 y Cos[x] certainly "involves x" in a nontrivial way.

Comment: Yes it does, but where did the 2 come from ? I used `SeedRandom[12345]` to get it.

Comment: If it chooses position {1,2,1} then that mystery 2a appears. I tried evaluating `expr[[{1, 2}]], expr[[{1, 2,1}]], expr[[{1, 2,1,1}]],expr[[{1, 2,1,1,1}]]` and adding more 1s increments the coefficient of `a`. I have no idea why.

Comment: Okay I was doing `expr[[thisPos]]`, but `Extract[expr,thisPos]` is what I wanted. It's working now.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your definition of random the method from [bill s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1783/bill-s) might have a problem in that some elements can be selected in more than one way.  For example in your `expr` the element at position `{3}` can be selected from either `{3, 2, 1, 2, 1}` or `{3, 3, 1, 1}`.  If we use `Position` to find all elements directly (rather than Dropping afterward) we avoid this.

```
expr = a x^3 + 2 y Cos[x] - Tanh[x^(y + 3)]/(x^4 - Sqrt[b]);

pos = Most @ Position[expr, s_ /; ! FreeQ[s, x]]

ReplacePart[expr, RandomChoice[pos] -> u]
```

---

> This never seems to replace the whole expression with $u$, even if I run it 100,000 times. Shouldn't that happen, as the Plus in the top of the TreeForm is eligible for replacement too?

I did not consider the whole expression to be a part.  The term `{}` in the return of `Position` represents the whole expression, but I dropped it using `Most` because `ReplacePart` cannot use this specification.

If you want to include that as a possibility I propose this instead:

```
pos = Position[expr, s_ /; ! FreeQ[s, x]]

Module[{x = expr}, x[[## & @@ RandomChoice @ pos]] = u; x]
```

Comment: This is exactly why they tell you not to accept answers too quickly!

Comment: This never seems to replace the whole expression with $u$, even if I run it 100,000 times. Shouldn't that happen, as the Plus in the top of the TreeForm is eligible for replacement too?

Comment: @flinty See the update.